# Node js - SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:.Error

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, dashboard

So I am using Statusdashboard (https://github.com/obazoud/statusdashboard), it is a simple tool to check whether a website is up or not (I know I can use Monit too, but I want to give Node JS a try that's why I am using this.)

This seems to work great when using 'http' in the settings file, but as soon as I try checking status of a website which uses 'https' protocol it gives out an error statement both on console and the dashboard - "SSL23_GET_SEVER_HELLO:unknown protocol". I figured it out that this has to do something with node HTTPS.

Just wondering if anyone has ever encountered this error before.

Comment: Getting the same error here... also looking for answers....

Comment: I tried using http instead of https and I can check the status of the website, though this solution doesn't work everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Reason for the error is probably that you service only speaks SSLv3. Node HTTPS uses SSLv2 as default.

I faced the same problem and solved it following this hint

[SSL Error in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091974/ssl-error-in-nodejs/12683325#comment25535766_12683325)

Hope this helps