# SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message

Tags: node.js, rest, ssl, kraken.js

I am using [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler), for making rest calls. I tested and got an expected response for the rest call to https://google.com. Now I am trying to make a call to another url location, but there is the following error message:
 **SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:741:**

I got the expected response using curl for the same url(url is different from here since I cannot share it. Sorry about that).

I also tried another rest client as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091974/ssl-error-in-nodejs), but get the same error message.

Is it to do with the certificates of the sites, since the SSL version used in both the cases is SSLv3_method.

I am using the following code for making the rest call:

```
   'use strict';
   module.exports = function (app) {
   app.get('/preference', function (req, res) {
        res.render('preference', {});
   });

    var rest = require('restler');

    rest.get('https://testlink/v1/path').on('complete', function(result) {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        console.log('Error:', result.message);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });

    };
```

It will be of great help if some one can provide me with their valuable inputs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solved it by adding

```
secureProtocol: 'SSLv3_method'
```

to the restler.request at node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js line:82 as shown below:

```
this.request = proto.request({
   host: this.url.hostname,
   port: this.url.port,
   path: this._fullPath(),
   method: this.options.method,
   headers: this.headers,
   rejectUnauthorized: this.options.rejectUnauthorized,
   secureProtocol: 'SSLv3_method'   //<---- add this
```

});