# SSL Error "unexpected message"

Tags: python, ssl

When I tested some Python code for different scenarios, I received the following error for the correct port, URL, username, and password:

```
SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message
```

I got the exact same error and traceback when I used a bogus username, and also when I used the correct username but the wrong password.  Could it be expecting SSL v3, and the version that is installed is older?  Just a guess.  I didn't see anything in the Python code that set the SSL version number.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so that people can examine your code and see if there is something wrong there.

Comment: Can you show us the code?  TLS doesn't know anything about usernames and passwords (unless you're using something like TLS-SRP, which I doubt), so the fact that you're getting that error suggests that you're not successfully setting up a TLS session.

Comment: It sounds like you are using Python2.7 and a 3rd party library like requests. If this is the case you should try this `pip install request[security]` most packages that I have run into that have to deal with this will have the `[security]` version.

Comment: Sorry, I am not allowed to post any code because it is proprietary.

Comment: For what it's worth, here are the last several lines of the traceback.  The Python code referenced is in GitHub at https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests

Answer (score 1):

Please can you post the code so that It is easy to resolve the problem.
This link may help you [[SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467826/ssl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellosslv3-alert-unexpected-message][1])

Comment: API.py line 88 -> API.py line 44 -> sessions.py line 335 -> sessions.py line 438 -> adapters.py line 331

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SSLAdapter](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user.html#ssladapter) to set the SSL and TLS versions.

I was getting a similar error and it was caused by the server using TLS 1.3, but I only have TLS 1.2 installed. So I had to do the following:

```py
from requests_toolbelt import SSLAdapter
import ssl
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.mount('https://', SSLAdapter(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2))
session.get(myurl)
```

If you can reach the server with a browser, you can check the SSL and TLS version by clicking on the lock or shield symbol next to the url.