# GET request will not return only within Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

For some reason this request GET never returns, but only in Node.js. I've tried in browser, curl, httparty, ruby's Net::Http, postman, clojure and they all work fine. Node.js will not.

This will return as you'd expect

```
echo "require('https').get('https://github.com/jakecraige.json', function(res) { console.log(res); });" | node
```

This never will return, it eventually throws an ECONNRESET

```
echo "require('https').get('https://gateway.rpx.realpage.com/rpxgateway/PricingAndAvailability.svc?wsdl', function(res) { console.log(res); });" | node
```

If anyone could provide some insight into this that would be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Zyrri in IRC directed me to here which solved the problem.

[SSL Error in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091974/ssl-error-in-nodejs)

Looks like it wants SSLv3_method from node.js

Answer (score 0):

```
$ curl 'https://gateway.rpx.realpage.com/rpxgateway/PricingAndAvailability.svc' -I
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Try providing an error handler and see what you get.

Comment: Looks like I needed to tack on the ?wsdl to the end of the url to get a valid request. Though the solution was different

Answer (score 0):

Your code hangs for me whichever URL I pick. I believe that's node trying to make sure we don't exit prematurely, running its event loop just in case. All other techniques you listed are synchronous, not event-driven. Also, `res` is probably not what you want to print, since it's the node's internal response object. Try this:

```
cat <<EOF | node
require("https").get("https://github.com/jakecraige.json",
  function(res) {
    var body = ''
    res.
      on('data', function(data) { body += data}).
      on('end', function() { console.log(body); process.exit(0); });
  }
);
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining @Constarr links with this original post I have this constructed request getting a valid response.

```
var https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = 'SSLv3_method';

https.get("https://gateway.rpx.realpage.com/rpxgateway/PricingAndAvailability.svc?wsdl", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

[Docs here](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback)