# EPROTO error when trying to make a proxied HTTPS request with node.js 0.12

Tags: node.js, heroku, https, proxy, openssl

At a high level, I am trying to use [Quota Guard Static](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quotaguardstatic) to talk to an IP limited API from a Heroku app from a node.js application. The API has its own node.js client implementation, but underneath the covers it's just an HTTP[S] api. The library uses [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) and [superagent-proxy](https://github.com/TooTallNate/superagent-proxy) underneath the covers to do the actual HTTP[S] requests.

In node 0.10, all worked fine. In node 0.12, I see errors like:

```
Error: write EPROTO 140735203734288:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:782:
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:775:14)
```

In io.js 2.02 I see:

```
Error: write EPROTO    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:844:11)
```

I tried globally using SSLv3 as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683325/149416), but it seemed to have no effect.

The proxy url is specified as an http URL with port 9293. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18142862/149416) suggested using port 443, but since the proxy provider is external to me, I cannot change it.

How might I get the proxied request to work in node 0.12?

Comment: The service running on port 9293 is not SSL. Client hello is responded with some other data and not Server Hello. Hence the error you see.

Comment: The proxy is both an HTTP and HTTPS proxy. It runs on port 9293, and is run by an external service, so I cannot change it. The same code ran fine on node 0.10, but doesn't work in node 0.12 or io 2.02

Answer (score 2):

Tim here from QuotaGuard. This seems to be an issue manifesting itself in the https-proxy-agent used by superagent-proxy for HTTPS requests causing the request to be made to the secure endpoint on the wrong port.

This is a simple example that should connect to Google on port 443.

```
var url = require('url');
var https = require('https');
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

// HTTP/HTTPS proxy to connect to
var proxy = process.env.QUOTAGUARDSTATIC_URL;
console.log('using proxy server %j', proxy);

// HTTPS endpoint for the proxy to connect to
var endpoint = process.argv[2] || 'https://www.google.com/';
console.log('attempting to GET %j', endpoint);
var opts = url.parse(endpoint);

// create an instance of the `HttpsProxyAgent` class with the proxy server information
var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxy);
opts.agent = agent;
https.get(opts, function (res) {
  console.log('"response" event!', res.headers);
  res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

The actual request is being made on port 80 so Google is rejecting it. Here are the HTTP headers:

```
["Proxy-Authorization: Basic Xgat28sa78saBZZ \r\n", "Host: www.google.com:80\r\n", "Connection: close\r\n"]
```

The same example on a patched version correctly connects to port 443 and works:

https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-https-proxy-agent/compare/master...timrwilliams:master

I suspect something has changed upstream which is causing the wrong port to be passed to https-proxy-agent but this type of problem is more appropriately discussed on [Github issues](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-https-proxy-agent/issues/7).

A quick fix would be switching to use the request library instead:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    proxy: process.env.QUOTAGUARDSTATIC_URL,
    url: 'https://www.google.com/',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'node.js'
    }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```