# Paypal using API with Curl error

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am working on Paypal with API as per ref of http://www.saaraan.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php

I am getting the below error. i tested in Couple of Servers but not succeded. The problem occurs while sending request to Paypal in that code.

> Error: SetExpressCheckout failed: Unknown SSL protocol error in
>   connection to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 (35)

Comment: possible duplicate of [cURL error 35 - Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.rkd.reuters.com:443](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384161/curl-error-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection-to-api-rkd-reuters-com)

Comment: @AmalMurali No, both are different queries. I can't able to understand, this is my server problem or coding problem. if u have any idea, please suggest. Thanks you.

Comment: @AmalMurali, used disable SSL by using this code. Still not working. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

Comment: The link you provided isn't loading.

Comment: @AndrewAngell, The same code is working in other server.